# bash scripting: pass string containing multiple parameters and filenames with spaces to ffmpeg

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg

I have a script that generates a text file with entries like:

```
-ss 5.5 -i "/path/vid 1.mp4" -t 3 "/path/vid out1.mp4"
```

But when I call ffmpeg with this string attached it fails.
If I quote the variable then ffmpeg considers the entire string as a single option, error "Option not found".
If I don't quote, then for some reason ffmpeg ignores the double quotes and reports **"/path/vid :No such file or directory.**

Even though it prints the input correctly as -i "/path/vid 1.mp4".

Replacing the double quotes around the filenames with single quotes doesn't help.
But when I pass the string to zenity and then manually copy it into the terminal, it works:

```
zenity --entry --entry-text "ffmpeg -nostdin $line2"
```

So I tried assigning the entire command to a var and then running
bash $var or exec $var, but no luck. Assigning it to an alias doesn't work either: "command not found"

Solution by Joan Estaban:

```
echo $stringvar | xargs ffmpeg
```

A short full script demonstrating the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash


fffile="/home/vume5/Desktop/dwhelper/bud grafting animation.mp4"

line="-ss 4.920000 -i \"$fffile\" -t 60.000000 -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a copy \"$fffile.cut.mkv\""

zenity --entry --entry-text "$line"

ffmpeg $line

read dummy
```

Comment: does manually trying the command `ffmpeg -ss 5.5 -i "/path/vid 1.mp4" -t 3 "/path/vid out1.mp4"` work?

Comment: Yes. I think the problem is that the double quotes are considered as filename characters. That's what it looks like. And I've no idea how to prevent this.

Comment: Just guessing, but would this help? `-ss 5.5 -i "\"/path/vid 1.mp4\"" -t 3 "\"/path/vid out1.mp4\""`

Comment: Nope. Then it's ""/path/vid :no such file.. The problem seems to be the opposite. That the quotes DO NOT get interpreted, and treated as filename chars.

Comment: You can try xargs: `cat my_params.txt | xargs -l ffmpeg`

Comment: Yeah! **echo "-nostdin $line2" | xargs ffmpeg** works!! thanks! @sp asic: it was just `ffmpeg -nostdin $line`, with the stringvar line being sth like `-ss 5.5 -i "/path/vid 1.mp4" -t 3 "/path/vid out1.mp4"`

Answer (score 3):

If your arguments may contain spaces and/or other special characters, then you can use an array to store them.

e.g.:

```
params=(-ss 5.5 -i "/path/vid 1.mp4" -t 3 "/path/vid out1.mp4")
mycommand "${params[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a text file with desired params for each execution you can use xargs:

`cat my_list_of_params.txt | xargs -l ffmpeg`

This execute ffmpeg as many times as lines on file. Param -l means that for each line on file must execute one time ffmeg